# Getting error: queries overflow the depth limit! when building with Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Amazingly there is not an exact match on the Internet for this error somehow. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

This is the error output:

```
Compiling lalrpop v0.17.2
Compiling typed-html-macros v0.2.2
Compiling typed-html v0.2.2
error: queries overflow the depth limit!

error: could not compile `typed-html` due to previous error
```

I have removed the build directory and recompiled everything. Changed the version of typed-html and done everything else I could think of to do.

So yeah, like I said, this error code string is not on the Internet, at least according to Google.

Comment: The error message comes with this [request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/100748) on 1.65.0, strangely it hides the error details. You can solve it via following these comments on this [issue](https://github.com/bodil/typed-html/issues/120#issuecomment-1160911231) or alternatively you can fork the latest version and change the recursion limit to 256(or more) declared in [lib.rs](https://github.com/bodil/typed-html/blob/0.2.2/typed-html/src/lib.rs#L1) (Note: currently crate has no maintainer)

Answer (score 0):

Using this version in Cargo.toml solves this. Thanks @Omer

`typed-html = { git = "https://github.com/bodil/typed-html", rev = "4c13ecca" }`